# How can I test access to encrypted (FileVault2) Time Machine partition?

Tags: time-machine, filevault, install

I have my Time Machine backups going to an external disk, and all of it is encrypted with FileVault2. I plan to do a fresh install of Mavericks on my local hard drive, but before wiping the disk, I want to make sure that I can still access my Time Machine backups.

As mentioned in this other [SO post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87081/accessing-my-old-filevault2-encrypted-drive-from-my-new-ssd), I should be able to use my FV key (and I vaguely remember using my account username/password to access data), but I want to be 100% sure.

Short of plugging this external drive into a separate OS X box (which I don't have), what else can I do to trigger the prompt for password/FV key/etc?  Would creating a new user on my machine be enough? Is there some Mavericks LiveCD mode (i.e. like Ubuntu)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can confirm this by booting from the Recovery Partition on the `Time Machine` disk and choosing to restore from a backup (without proceeding with the restore).

Here are the steps:

- Connect the external hard disk with the encrypted `Time Machine` backup
- Boot (or reboot) the system and during startup hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key so that it shows you the list of available volumes to boot from
- Select the **Recovery HD** from the `Time Machine` disk to boot from it
- Choose **Restore From Time Machine Backup** from the list of actions
- Select the encrypted `Time Machine` volume from the list
- Enter the Fila Vault 2 password when prompted
- Wait for it to show the list of available backups from the `Time Machine` volume
- Restart the system now that you have verified the availability of the backup

Answer (score 1):

you could delete the key in your keychain. After plugin the disk back in, the password prompt should pop up

Comment: While this is good, part of my concern is that I saved the wrong key/password for the Time Machine backups, so before deleting/clearing anything from Keychain, I best confirm I have access :)